# Listener failed to start

Tags: database, linux, oracle, listener, virtual-machine

I have a virtual Machine on VMWare Player: Oracle 11g on Linux Centos.
Since I haven't used it for 2 years, I don't remember almost anything,and when I try to startup the db it says listener is down, and when I try to start listener it says:

```
TNSLSNR for Linux Version 11.2. 0.1.0 - Production
System Parameter file is /oracle/product/11gR2/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/srvlinux/listener/alert/log.xml
Error listening on: (ADRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12542: TNS:address already in use
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adater error
  TNS-00512: Address already in use
   Linux Error: 98: Address already in use
```

What do I have to configure exactly? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

netstat -tulpn | grep :1521

```
tcp 0 0 :::1521 :::* LIST 
EN 3369/tnslsnr
```

EDIT:

lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 11-DEC-2012 16:09:54
```

sqlplus / as sysdba

```
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

Comment: That suggests the listener is actually up. Or at least something is listening on 1521, it would unusual for it to be something else - `lsnrctl status` might be interesting. What says it's down, and when? Maybe your client is looking for a different port, or your `tnsnames.ora` has the wrong port (or address), or your DB has `local_listener` set to something else. Does your `listener.ora` have more than one listener configured maybe, but only one has started?

Comment: What process has taken 1521? `netstat -tulpn | grep :1521`

Comment: Migrate to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: tcp 0 0 :::1521 :::* LIST EN 3369/tnslsnr

Comment: Show the environment (ORACLE_SID; ORACLE_HOME): `set | grep ORA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORA-12162 usually means you don't have `ORACLE_SID` set - not that it's wrong, but it hasn't been set at all, or has not been exported (depending on your shell). That doesn't tell you anything about whether the database is up, and doesn't imply the listener is down - so don't know if you got a different message from a different connection attempt. Clearly the listener is up on port 1521, from the details you added to the question.

If you're using something Bourne-y (sh, ksh, bash etc.) you need to set and export your `ORACLE_SID`:

```
export ORACLE_SID=my_sid
```

If you can't remember the SID you can go `grep -ef | grep ora_pmon_`; if that shows anything then the SID is the end of the process name, and the database is up. If it doesn't then look at the output of `lsnrctl status` and see if anything is registered, or look in `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` - files in there might include the SID in their names too.

You might also need to `export ORACLE_HOME` if you haven't already, but it sounds like you have, probably from your `.profile`/`.bashrc` etc.