# can't start Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

I just install Oracle, but can't start it. i get error below:

```
root@coding:/u01/binaries# $ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 15-NOV-2015 15:57:30

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/coding/listener/alert/log.xml
Error listening on: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12542: TNS:address already in use
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    TNS-00512: Address already in use
      Linux Error: 98: Address already in use

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

Comment: This question is better suited in either [the DBA Stack](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux Stack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or in the [Serverfault Stack](http://serverfault.com/). Please search for the error message "`Linux Error: 98: Address already in use`" at first.

Comment: See also [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300464/listener-failed-to-start).

Comment: What does `lsnrctl status` say? As @baliman suggests, your listener may just already be running. Otherwise you'll need to look at the log that refers to or see what else is running on your server - neither of which we can help you with. Why are you running this as root rather than a dedicated Oracle user account?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is already using port 1521

Try a netstat -a | grep 1521

And look what process is using this port

Johan

Comment: tcp6       0      0 [::]:1521               [::]:*                  LISTEN